# cannot run "mv some_file.txt ~/myproject/ " command in the cmd ipython

Tags: shell, ipython

I have installed Anaconda in the Windows 10, I am able to run the IPython in cmd with some Linux commands like 'ls' and 'pwd' but when I try to run the 'mv' command
"

> mv some_file.txt ~/myproject/

it gives the error  :

> `File "<ipython-input-28-304da5ec8c93>", line 1.`

Can someone please tell me what would be the correct format to run this shell code in
command prompt IPython.

Answer (score 1):

> to_run: mv ../myproject.txt ./

> In [45]: !move myproject.txt C:\Users\user_name

> ```
>    1 file(s) moved.
> ```

> In [46]: pwd

> Out[46]: 'C:\Users\user_name\folder_name'

> In [48]: cd ..

> C:\Users\use_name

> ******* to_run:  cp myproject.txt myproject\

> In [49]: !copy myproject.txt C:\Users\user_name\myproject

> ```
>    1 file(s) copied.
> ```

Thanks @Ahmed Yehia you lead me to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `mv` is not a supported magic command on Windows. Going through the docs I couldn't find an equivalent magic command but this might help you:

`!move some_file.txt C:\Users\Some_User\myproject\`

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thankyou for your reply, I tried this in the command prompt and still I am getting the error as follows:

`In [22]: !ls  `
`batman.py  testcats.py  `
`In [23]: !pwd `
`/c/Users/tanma/myproject  `
`In [24]: !move test_file_2.txt C:\Users\tanma\myproject\ `
`The system cannot find the file specified.  `
`In [25]: !move test_file_2.txt /c/Users/tanma/myproject `
`The system cannot find the file specified.  `
`In [26]: `